# where syslog store error messages

Tags: c, linux, syslog

> syslog() generates a log message
>
> syslog(LOG_ERR, "%s failed: %d (%m)", str, errno); syslog(LOG_NOTICE,
>   "%s failed: %d (%m)", str, errno); syslog(LOG_INFO,"%s",str);

where does it store this info?

I can not find any file in the server by the name of LOG_ERR, LOG_NOTICE,LOG_INFO.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under **Linux** you can find them here : `/var/log/syslog`, if you run this simple program:

```
#include <syslog.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        /* Various syslog messages */
        syslog (LOG_CRIT, "%s", "That's critic");
        syslog(LOG_ALERT, "An alert\n");
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "Error on this DAEMON\n");

        return 0;
}
```

and open a terminal and run this:

```
toc@UnixServer:/var/log$ tail -f syslog
```

You should see something like this:

```
Aug 18 08:42:21 TarekServer SYSLOG: That's critic
Aug 18 08:42:21 TarekServer SYSLOG: An alert
Aug 18 08:42:21 TarekServer SYSLOG: Error on this DAEMON
```

Answer (score 1):

They get dumped into the syslog buffer where `syslogd`/`rsyslogd` picks them up and puts them in the appropriate locations as determined by its configuration in `/etc`.